# ZSH: How do I test whether a group of files exist or not?

Tags: testing, zsh

I've got a group of files with **only one** specific extension under one specific directory. How do I check whether I've got at least one of those files. If at least one file with that specific extension is present, then print *at least one file matching your extension is present in your directory*. If not, then print *no files of that specific extension exist in your directory*.

Also, when no file of a specific extension is present, I've got the following error message that I'm not able to get rid of, even if I use `2>/dev/null` redirection: `zsh: no matches found: *.mkv` (and hence, behaving differently from Bash)

Comment: You create an array with all the files matching the pattern, and then test the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the error, use the `N` glob qualifier to enable the `NULL_GLOB` option, replacing the error with an empty result.

```
% print *.mkv
zsh: no matches found: *.mkv
% print *.mkv(N)

%
```

For the rest of the problem, you can capture the result in an array named `result`, then get the number of matches by checking the size of the array with `$#result`.

If it would be useful, you can also limit which matches a pattern produces. For example, `*.mkv[1,5]` produces (at most) the first 5 results. The second number is optional; a single value only provides that one element.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved as follows:

```bash
setopt no_nomatch
if ls *.mkv 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then echo OK; fi
setopt nomatch # Undo the change after evaluation (just in case)
```

Inspired by:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310553
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/257141

Good read on the topic:

https://scriptingosx.com/2019/06/moving-to-zsh-part-3-shell-options/

Comment: Although the above answer worked fine for me I accidently found the following to be working equally well: `if ( ls *.mkv ) 1> /dev/null 2>&1; then echo OK; fi`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the directory you are checking is `my_dir`:

```
all_files=(my_dir/*(ND))
if (( #all_files > 0 ))
then
  echo at least one entry exists in my_dir
fi
```

This would also include **subdirectories** within `my_dir`. If you are only interested in plain files, do instead a

```
all_files=(my_dir/*(ND,))
```